# Determine if series converges (mixed ln, sin and polynomials)

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, asymptotics

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\ln^{5} (2n^{7}+13) + 10 \sin n}{n \ln^6 (n^{7/8} + 2 \sqrt n - 1) \ln (\ln (n + (-1)^{n}))}$$

I don't even know how to start, any hints how to solve so complicated sums?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Note that terms by term $\ln^5(2n^7+13) \approx \ln^5 n,|10 \sin n| \le 10, n^{7/8} + 2\sqrt{n} - 1 \approx n^{7/8}$ and $n + (-1)^n \approx n$.

Comment: what does $ \approx $ here mean? Shouldn't I show that one is bigger than the other to use comparison test or something like that?

Comment: And sorry, there should be $ \ln ^{5} (2n^{7} + 13)$, already fixed that

Comment: @abc2343 $\approx$ means asymptotically equivalent, i.e. if $f(x) \approx g(x)$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = 1$$